# Laravel Moderation showing only accepted posts

Tags: laravel

I installed hootlex-moderation package on my current project and it's working  fine. But the problem is that it is showing only accepted posts, I found solution for that on my past project and it was 'strict' moderation set to false, but this time that is not solution. Do you guys know how to fix that?

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PostsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $post = Post::all();
        return view('posts.tabela')->with('posts', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {

        return view('posts.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'br_kesice' => 'required',
            'ime' => 'required',
            'br_telefona' => 'required',
            'posao' => 'required',
            'cijena' => 'required',
            'placanje' => 'required',
            'popust' => 'required',
            'datum_preuz' => 'required',
            'datum_izdav' => 'required',
            'smjena' => 'required',
            'radnik' => 'required',

        ]);

        $post = new Post;
        $post->br_kesice = $request->input('br_kesice');
        $post->ime = $request->input('ime');
        $post->br_telefona = $request->input('br_telefona');
        $post->posao = $request->input('posao');
        $post->cijena = $request->input('cijena');
        $post->placanje = $request->input('placanje');
        $post->popust = $request->input('popust');
        $post->datum_preuz = $request->input('datum_preuz');
        $post->datum_izdav = $request->input('datum_izdav');
        $post->smjena = $request->input('smjena');
        $post->radnik = $request->input('radnik');

        $post->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $post->save();

        return redirect('/home');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }


    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);

        if(auth()->user()->id !==$post->user_id){
            return redirect('/posts')->with('error', 'Nedozvoljen pristup!');
        }
        return view('posts.edit', compact('post', 'id'))->with('post', $post);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        switch($request->get('approve'))
        {
            case 0:
                Post::postpone($id);
                break;
            case 1:
                Post::approve($id);
                break;
            case 2:
                Post::reject($id);
                break;
            case 3:
                Post::postpone($id);
                break;
            default:    
                break;

        }





        return redirect('/home');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

moderation.php file

```
<?php
return array(
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Status column
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'status_column' => 'status',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Moderated At column
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */
    'moderated_at_column' => 'moderated_at',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Moderated By column
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Moderated by column is disabled by default.
    | If you want to include the id of the user who moderated a resource set
    | here the name of the column.
    | REMEMBER to migrate the database to add this column.
    */
    'moderated_by_column' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Strict Moderation
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | If Strict Moderation is set to true then the default query will return
    | only approved resources.
    | In other case, all resources except Rejected ones, will returned as well.
    */
    'strict' => false,


);
```

My migrations

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('br_kesice');
            $table->string('ime');
            $table->string('br_telefona');
            $table->mediumText('posao');
            $table->string('cijena');
            $table->string('placanje');
            $table->string('popust');
            $table->string('datum_preuz');
            $table->string('datum_izdav');
            $table->string('smjena');
            $table->string('radnik');
            $table->smallInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->dateTime('moderated_at')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

This is my edit blade

```
<select name="approve">
                <option value="0" @if($post->status==0)selected @endif>Pending</option>
                <option value="1" @if($post->status==1)selected @endif>Approve</option>
                <option value="2" @if($post->status==2)selected @endif>Reject</option>
                <option value="3" @if($post->status==3)selected @endif>Postponed</option> 
</select>
```

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. Your configuration, code etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to all of this. Here is my code, please help, if you need anything more comment and I will add

Comment: so what you need is to get all the posts? could you add your `Post` model into the question? **EDIT** based on [the package page](https://packagist.org/packages/hootlex/laravel-moderation), it shows that you can just `Post::withAnyStatus()->get();`.... have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, I need to get all posts, but my moderation is showing just accepted ones. Here is my Post model

Comment: I tried but nothing happend

Comment: Did you try clearing your config cache? If you're using homestead, you'll need to run `cd ~/Homestead && vagrant ssh`, change directory to your projects root and run `php artisan config:clear`. If you're not using homestead, do the same without the `cd` and `vagrant ssh` part.

Comment: HELPED! THANK YOU !!

Comment: ```php artisan config:clear```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Hootlex\Moderation\Moderatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;


class Post extends Model
{

   use Moderatable;

    protected $table = 'posts';

    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is my HomeController, I made it to be page for user that is currently logged in. Here is my code..

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('home')->with('posts', $user->posts);
    }


}
```

And when I add Post::withAnyStatus()->get(); like this...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $posts = Post::withAnyStatus()->get();
        return view('home')->with('posts', $posts);
    }


}
```

It shows me all posts, and it is working but I need it to show only posts of that user_id that is currently logged in. Any solutions on this?